# Ejabberd LDAP SCRAM password authentication

Tags: ldap, ejabberd

I have set`auth_password_format: scram` in ejabberd.yml and ldap auth method.

LDAP authentication works only for passwords in plaintext.
I can even set scram hash value as a password in my xmpp client and successfully login, since ejabberd checks it as a plain text against LDAP record, but how do I make ejabberd hash the password with scram before checking it against the LDAP record?

I thought auth_password_format would do that, but apparently it still thinks userPassword attribute in the LDAP record is in plain text.

Is there some additional check that ejabberd preforms on the userPassword value to see if it is indeed scram and then fails for some reason? Or is it ignoring auth_password_format option when ldap is set as auth method? Or something else entirely?

Is there a way as a non-erlang developer that I can make this work? The only idea I have is to use external auth scripts if ejabberd cant use scram and ldap together for some reason, but I would really like it if I can just set this up in the configuration file instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ejabberd source code, `scram` is mentioned in ejabberd_auth.erl, ejabberd_auth_mnesia.erl and ejabberd_auth_sql.erl. There is no mention to scram in the other authentication methods, which points to what you concluded.

In this sense, I later noticed that the SCRAM section mentions only internal (Mnesia) and SQL auth methods:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/#scram

I would say that external auth will not support it either.